# how to pause/resume of file during uploading on server in rails

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, jquery-file-upload

i want to make a resume able video up loader in rails .
what is the best way to make this .should i use to fineuploadr , or jquery-file-uploader.

is it possibale with paperclip gem ruby or not ?
I tried it with jquery file uploader plugin . 
here is my _form.

```js
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#video_file").bind('change', function() {
    console.log(this.files[0].size);
  });

  $("#submit-upl").click(function(){
    $('#new_video').fileupload({
      maxNumberOfFiles: 1,
      maxChunkSize: 10000000, // 10 MB
      type: 'PATCH',
      add: function (e, data) {
        var that = this;
        $.getJSON(resume_path, { file: data.files[0].name }, function (result) {
            var file = result.file;
            data.uploadedBytes = file && file.size;
            $.blueimp.fileupload.prototype
                .options.add.call(that, e, data);
        });
      }
   });
  })
     
})
</script>
```

```html
<%= form_for video , method: :post , :multipart => true do |f| %>
  <% if video.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
      <h2><%= pluralize(video.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this video from being saved:</h2>
      <ul>
      <% video.errors.full_messages.each do |message| %>
        <li><%= message %></li>
      <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :file %>
    <%= f.file_field :file %>
  </div>
  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit "save" , id: "submit-upl" %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

```
 def create
@video = Video.new(video_params)
file = params[:video][:file]
  File.open(Rails.root.join('app','assets', 'images', file.original_filename), 'ab') do |f|
    f.write(file.read)
  end

  @video.file =  file.original_filename
respond_to do |format|
  if @video.save
    format.html { redirect_to @video, notice: 'Video was successfully created.' }
    format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @video }
  else
    format.html { render :new }
    format.json { render json: @video.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
  end
end
```

end

Comment: File uploaders won't be able to help in your case. File uploaders generally send whole file object. So, if any network issue comes, it will fail completely. You need to find a way to send file in chunks of packets, like downloader managers, or torrents.

Comment: How to send file in chunks of packets . and how i can remember that how many chunks have been sent ,on resume

Comment: You can not achieve this with only javascript or jquery. Check node-webkit with Chromium or any browser you wish to be supported. To track number of chunks sent or receive, you have to add this logic on your server side which will acknowledge client with the number of packets received and on failure of any packet, it should send some unique identifier for that packet, to client.